# Another limit points task.

Tags: limits, metric-spaces

Let $x_n, y_n$ -- two numerical sequences with pairwise distinct terms (i.e $x_i \neq x_j$ and $y_i \neq y_j$ for all $i \neq j$).

We decided that $\lim_{n \to \infty} (x_ny_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n + y_n) = 5$.

The question is to find all limit points of the set $A$, where:
$A = \{e^{x_n} + e^{y_n} \ | \ n \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Definition of limit point which I know: $a \in X, A \subset X$ is limit point if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ punctured ball $B_{\varepsilon}(a)$ contains an element from $A$.

In our case $X = \mathbb{R}$.

I found that:
$x = \lim_{n \to \infty} (x_n) = \frac{5 + \sqrt{5}}{2}$
$y =\lim_{n \to \infty} (y_n) = \frac{5 - \sqrt{5}}{2}$

With solving a system

$xy=5$

$x+y=5$.

(We've got case with swapped values of x and y, but it's easy to show that we can do the same for them if we find solution).

My idea is to find $z = \lim z_n$, where $z_n = e^{x_n} + e^{y_n}$. And then we can say that limit point is only $z$ (from the limit defenition).

But I've got some troubles with finding this limit.

Comment: Maybe this helps: $\frac{x_n}{y_n}+\frac{y_n}{x_n}+2=\frac{x_n^2+y_n^2+2x_ny_n}{x_ny_n}=\frac{(x_n+y_n)^2}{x_ny_n}\to 5$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{x_n}{y_n}+\frac{y_n}{x_n}\to 3$

Comment: The question is interesting, but you should provide more details of what have you tried. Otherwise, it risks being closed due to the incomplete context.

Comment: Fixed,  yes. Thank you!

Comment: HOw do you find $\lim x_n$ and $\lim y_n$?

Comment: Pretty easy system: xy=5, x+y = 5.

Comment: How do you know that the limits exists? @Someone

Comment: @TitoEliatron .You don't know. See my A.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x_n$ and $y_n$ do not necessarily converge. For example let $u_n$ be strictly decreasing to $x$ and let $v_n$ be strictly increasing to $y;\,$ let $(x_n,y_n)=(u_n,v_n)$ when $n$ is even;$\,$ let $(x_n,y_n)=(v_n,u_n)$ when $n$ is odd.

Let $S_n=x_n+y_n$ and $P_n=x_ny_n.$ Let $D_n= S_n^2-4P_n.$ Then  $\{x_n,y_n\}=\{(S_n+\sqrt {D_n})/2,\,(S_n-\sqrt {D_n})/2\}.$ Let $b_n=\max(x_n,y_n)$ and $c_n=\min(x_n,y_n).$ Then $b_n\to x$ and $c_n\to y.$ Therefore $$e^{x_n}+e^{y_n}=e^{b_n} +e^{c_n}\to e^x+e^y=^{def} z.$$

So $z$ is the unique limit-point of $A$ if $A$ is an infinite set, which it could be.

It is possible that $A$ is a finite set. For example if $x<x_n<\ln z$ for every $n,$ with $x_n\to x,$ and $y_n=\ln  (z-e^{x_n}).$ Then $A=\{z\}.$

Comment: HOw do you know that $D_n>0$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$? I say that because $D_n=(x_n-y_n)^2$, so $\sqrt{D_n}=|x_n-y_n|$ (i arrived there by myself); but I couldn't use it since it is possible to $(D_n)_n$ to be, for example, an alternating sequence.

Comment: @TitoEliatron . $S^2_n\to 25$ and $4P_n\to 20$ so $D_n\to 5$ so $\{n: D_n\not >0\}$ is finite. It doesn't matter whether $D_n$ is $0$ for some finite collection of $n$'s.

Comment: Sorrt, @DanielWainfleet I wrote it wrong. My question should be:
How do you know that $\sqrt{D_n}=x_n-y_n$ and not $|x_n-y_n|$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron . We don't know whether or not $x_n\ge y_n$ and it doesn't matter. The reason $ e^{x_n}+e^{y_n}=e^{b_n}+e^{c_n}$ is NOT because $x_n\ge y_n.$ It is because $[x_n=b_n\land y_n=c_n]\lor [x_n=c_n\land y_n=b_n].$

Comment: I'm trying to understand everything.... Why is $b_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$?

Comment: @TitoEliatron . $b_n=(S_n+\sqrt {D_n})/2 \to x$ because $S_n\to 5$ and $D_n\to 5.$